# add object to another array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can any one please help me how to add objects to another array of Objects

```
myArray = [

        {
            "A" :{
                values  
                },
            "B" :{
                values
                },
             "C":{
                 values
             }
         }

]
```

another Object:

```
 {
      "D":{

         values 
        },
      "E":{
         values 
      }

    }
```

I want to add next objects like D and E to My Array of First Object.

it shuold be like this

```
[
    { 

   "A":{},
   "B":{},
   "C":{},
   "D":{}, 
   "E":{}
}
]
```

Cna you help me any one how to add this objects

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you have this in an array? Won't a single object can hold all these objects as children?

Comment: objectname={content};  myArray.push(objectname);

Comment: Hi @ Arunprasanth, can you please explain clearly if don't mine. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According  to my understanding you have one array of object i.e.

```
myArray = [{"A" :{},"B" :{},"C":{}}]
```

and you want to add some property in that object so just use

```
myArray[0].D={};
myArray[0].E={};

console.log(myArray[0]);
```

And if You want to add more objects in Array use push method

```
var obj={"A1" :{},"B1" :{},"C1":{}}
```

if you want to add in myArray then use

```
myArray.push(obj);
```

yours array of object will be

```
myArray = [{"A" :{},"B" :{},"C":{}},
           {"A1" :{},"B1" :{},"C1":{}}]
```

Hope it clears yours doubt.

Comment: how can i more than objects i need to add, is it any idea, can you please share, Thanks

Comment: So if you want to Add objects in Array then use push method .

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
myarray=[{"A":"e1"},{"B":"e2"},{"C":"e4"}];
      var obj={"D":"e5"};                
       myarray.push(obj);
          alert(myarray[3].D)
```

will alert e5

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ztr1szv9/)**

Update :

```
myarray=[{"A":"e1"},{"B":"e2"},{"C":"e4"}];
var obj={"D":"e6","E":"e9"};                
       myarray.push(obj);
          alert(myarray[3].F)
```

will alert e9